# Plus icon appearing incorrectly in grid

Tags: jqgrid

For my grid I have the following configuration:

```
        subGrid: true,
        subGridOptions: {
            // configure the icons from theme rolloer
            plusicon: "fa fa-plus",
            minusicon: "fa fa-minus",
            openicon: "fa fa-expand"
        },
```

When the grid is displayed, the wrong icon is showing up:

[image]

This is the generated html:

[image]

How do I get the normal +/- icons to show up?

Comment: In order to resolve the problem we need more information:
1. Full jqGrid setup.
2. Which CSS framework is used
3. What css and js jqGrid files are loaded in the head of the document?
If possible provide test full example .
It seems you use fontAwesome icons, but you do not have 
configured the grid to use them. See the options styleUI and iconSet
in the docs.